# How to add flags to MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I know how to add flags on Wikipedia but I'm trying to add flags on MediaWiki and don't know how. I am new to MediaWiki.

When I use "flagicon|GBR" on my main page, it comes up at "Template: Flagicon" as a red link. When I click on it, it takes me to a blank template page and I have no clue what to add here. I am assuming something goes here?

Can someone help me out please? What do I write to get a flag?

It's absolutely annoying lol

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`flagicon` is a [MediaWiki template](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates). You can import it to use it on your wiki.